# Is it allowed to write a SQL function in PostgreSQL to return more then one data type?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

I am working on a compatibility issue, I want to create a SQL function which can return an int or a Varchar based on the conditions in the program.

For example, I have a function named foo.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION foo(param VARCHAR(100))
-- Which datatype I should use here?
RETURNS SOME_DATATYPE AS
$$
  SELECT
    CASE UPPER(param)
        WHEN 'varchar'  THEN CAST((SELECT 'varchar_value') AS varchar)
        WHEN 'int'      THEN CAST((SELECT 1426598) AS int)
        ELSE param||' is not supported.'
        END
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

For the following queries, I am expecting output as follows.

```
select pg_typeof(foo('varchar')) from dual;
--I am expecting varchar as output.

select pg_typeof(foo('int')) from dual;
--I am expecting int as output.
```

Please suggest if such a feature is there, Or any alternative I can try to achieve the same.

Comment: A CASE expression returns a single value and all `WHEN` parts of such an expression must return the same data type, so that part will already not work. But "*can return an int or a Varchar based on the conditions in the program*"  is also not possible.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `CAST((SELECT 1426598) AS int)` can be simplified to `CAST(1426598 AS int)` the SELECT is completely useless

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing would be to overload the function:

```sql
create or replace function foo(param text)
  returns text
$$
select param;
$$
language sql;

create or replace function foo(param int)
  returns int
$$
select param;
$$
language sql;

create or replace function foo(param date)
  returns int
$$
select param;
$$
language sql;
```